# Add array of url as InputSource in ImageSlideshow

Tags: swift

I want to add array of urls

```
let afNetworkingSource = [AFURLSource(urlString: "https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/balloon_flight_plant_91681_1920x1080.jpg")!, 
                          AFURLSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463595373836-6e0b0a8ee322?w=1080")!]
```

Comment: have a look at my answer and let me know if you have any doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var afNetworkingSource = Array<AFURLSource>()

if  let source = getUrlSource("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/balloon_flight_plant_91681_1920x1080.jpg") {
    afNetworkingSource.append(source)
}



func getUrlSource(str:String) -> AFURLSource? {
     return AFURLSource(urlString: str) {
}
```

Comment: Always Welcome happy to help, also accept the answer.